# Xuggle and red5 without red5 adapter

Tags: java, flash, streaming, red5, xuggle

As I understand xuggle has built in rtmp support as of version 3.4 and as a result they deprecated the red5 adapter. So in order to stream to a running red5 instance, I searched a bit in stack overflow and found this question:

[How to transmit live video from within a Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214422/how-to-transmit-live-video-from-within-a-java-application)

I took the code as it is and just pasted it into my Netbeans Project. However, it doesn't work. I played around it a while and then decided to observe the messages exchange between the client (on my machine) and the red5 server.

Here is the exchange:
http://i53.tinypic.com/34e4z5x.jpg

You might notice that in MI2 my client has already called its releaseStream(stream1)
This happens in the code block:

```
 int retVal = container.open(url, IContainer.Type.WRITE, containerFormat_live, true, false);
```

As I dug deeper into the exchange I noticed:

http://i53.tinypic.com/rwnn8y.jpg

And that made me wonder if I wasn't advertising a wrong flash version to the server. But how am I supposed to correct that?

Anybody got that example working with xuggler 3.4 and red5 0.9.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using Xuggler 4.x (tip of tree) and compiling with librtmp as that fixes A LOT of RTMP problems.

- Art