# How can I generate live video stream and stream via servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, video-streaming, xuggle

I am looking for an example of how to generate a live video stream from a series of images and stream it via java servlet.

I can generate a video from images using [xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/). I tried using Red5 but I'm not convinced that it is what I need. I would rather stream directly via servlet from within my web app. I've also looked at this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214422/how-to-transmit-live-video-from-within-a-java-application), but it seems that xuggle has deprecated/removed some of the functionality that the code example is using.

Comment: As far as I understand what you want to do, it is Red5 what you want to use. Although, what do you exactly mean by "stream that video live to a servlet"?

Comment: @bpgergo - I would just like to display the live stream from a servlet

Comment: Also when I tried to deploy the Red5 Server I couldn't find any definitive examples of how to set up the server and then configure it with live streaming.

Comment: "to display the live stream from a servlet": AFAK you'll need a so called "streaming media server" (like red5) to do so. Here's a list of such servers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_streaming_media_systems Regarding Red5 configuration: I used Red5 several years ago and do not remember much.