# RTMP Streaming to Red5 using Xuggler

Tags: java, red5, rtmp, xuggler

I have the following problem: in my application I am supposed to connect to a VNC server, grab the icoming images and both save them as a video file (this part works) and publish as a RTMP stream to Red5 server.

Most of the video encoding part is based on Xuggler's screen recording tutorial app ( http://wiki.xuggle.com/MediaTool_Introduction#How_To_Take_Snapshots_Of_Your_Desktop ).

However, being a beginner in Java I can't seem to get the live streaming part to work. I know I am supposed to use IContainer, but even after reading this: [How to transmit live video from within a Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214422/how-to-transmit-live-video-from-within-a-java-application) and several other posts I don't really know how to adapt that to my application. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!