# Youtube Live Streaming API - Stream is not appearing in Youtube

Tags: youtube-api, xuggler, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to stream video from my webcam to YouTube using Xuggler and YouTube's live streaming API. I was successful in connecting to YouTube and in creating a broadcast by following the example provided [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/).

I used Xuggler to encode the videos and send it to YouTube using the code below. The steps for encoding the videos is taken from a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214422/how-to-transmit-live-video-from-within-a-java-application).

I am not getting any error in my console when I run my program, but the stream is not going live in Youtube. In Youtube Live control room, it keeps showing a message that "We are not receiving data from your encoder. Please make sure it is configured correctly in the Ingestion Settings page."

What am I doing wrong? Any help or pointers will be highly appreciated...

```java
String url =  returnedStream.getCdn().getIngestionInfo().getIngestionAddress(); 
String fileName = returnedStream.getCdn().getIngestionInfo().getStreamName() ;

IContainer container = IContainer.make();
IContainerFormat containerFormat_live = IContainerFormat.make();
containerFormat_live.setOutputFormat("flv", url + "/"+ fileName, null);
container.setInputBufferLength(0);
int retVal = container.open(url + "/"+ fileName, IContainer.Type.WRITE, containerFormat_live);
if (retVal < 0) {
    System.err.println("Could not open output container for live stream");
    System.exit(1);
}

Dimension size = WebcamResolution.QVGA.getSize();

IStream stream = container.addNewStream(0);
IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();
ICodec codec = ICodec.findEncodingCodec(ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264);
coder.setNumPicturesInGroupOfPictures(4);
coder.setCodec(codec);
coder.setBitRate(500000);
coder.setPixelType(IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);
coder.setHeight(size.height);
coder.setWidth(size.width);

System.out.println("[ENCODER] video size is " + size.width + "x" + size.height);
coder.setFlag(IStreamCoder.Flags.FLAG_QSCALE, true);
coder.setGlobalQuality(0);
IRational frameRate = IRational.make(24, 1);
coder.setFrameRate(frameRate);
coder.setTimeBase(IRational.make(frameRate.getDenominator(), frameRate.getNumerator()));

coder.open();
container.writeHeader();
long firstTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
long lastTimeStamp = -1;
int i = 0;
try {
    //Robot robot = new Robot();
    Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
    webcam.setViewSize(size);
    webcam.open(true);

    while (i < framesToEncode) {
        //long iterationStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //grab the screenshot
        BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
        //convert it for Xuggler
        BufferedImage currentScreenshot = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        currentScreenshot.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        //start the encoding process
        IPacket packet = IPacket.make();
        IConverter converter = ConverterFactory.createConverter(currentScreenshot, IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);
        long timeStamp = (now - firstTimeStamp) * 1000; 
        IVideoPicture outFrame = converter.toPicture(currentScreenshot, timeStamp);
        if (i == 0) {
            //make first frame keyframe
            outFrame.setKeyFrame(true);
        }
        outFrame.setQuality(0);
        coder.encodeVideo(packet, outFrame, 0);
        outFrame.delete();
        if (packet.isComplete()) {
            container.writePacket(packet);
            System.out.println("[ENCODER] writing packet of size " + packet.getSize() + " for elapsed time " + ((timeStamp - lastTimeStamp) / 1000));
            lastTimeStamp = timeStamp;
        }
        System.out.println("[ENCODER] encoded image " + i + " in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - now));
        i++;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Math.max((long) (1000 / frameRate.getDouble()) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - now), 0));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're sending rtmp-compliant video to YouTube's rtmp ingestion address?  What happens when you check the status of your `LiveBroadcast` or the `cdn.format` of your `LiveStream`?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I used very same tutorial as you, and end up by uploading video ignored by youtube. If you find a solution, please post it here, I lost hours by googling and found nothing. Also, do you have version with audio? This is only video and I need to stream audio too.

Comment: Can  you please have a look on my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449366/how-to-send-video-stream-for-live-event-using-youtube-broadcast-in-java

Comment: @JAL Can you please have a look on my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449366/how-to-send-video-stream-for-live-event-using-youtube-broadcast-in-java

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I couldn't find a solution for this. I ended up using Wowza streaming instead.