# Can't see video in preview YouTube live/Stream status changes Good to No Data YouTube

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to `broadcast` my `video` on `YouTube` in java program. So far, I am able to ingest video in `ingestion url/address`. And, when I run my program I get these screens:

First Screen :

[image]

Then when I click on `Preview` button, I get Second Screen:

[image]

Nothing happens not can see in video on show Please stand by. After 3-4 seconds, I get Third Screen:

[image]

I really don't know what is the exact problem. Why I am not able to see anything though I am ingesting video in `ingestion url/address`. And, why screen things get changed after 3-4 seconds.

More details:

I am working on MacBook air, installed FMLE but when I open FMLE it says No capture device detected.

Modified code from:

[Github](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/java)

[Youtube Live Streaming API - Stream is not appearing in Youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915767/youtube-live-streaming-api-stream-is-not-appearing-in-youtube)

I want to know whether its a code issue or FMLE.

Comment: @JAL Can you please answer to my question?

Comment: Can you post some more info about your Adobe FMLE settings?  It's really hard to debug without knowing how your encoder is set up.

Comment: Did you follow the encoder setup instructions [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2907883?hl=en&ref_topic=2853713)?

Comment: @JAL Thanks for reply. I have gone through it but didn't understand. So what I did is downloaded FMLE & backup & profile xmls but don't know what to do next?

Comment: @JAL Did the steps but nothing happens, please help me

Comment: @JAL I have imported profile xml by opening profile in File & set it there. What should I do next, please help me

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today. I searched around for answers and it looks like deleting the live event is the solution. Then start a new one over again. I did this and it worked.

Comment: But creating new live event will form different stream name. So how it is possible?