# How to stream video(only) using xuggler

Tags: video, video-streaming, xuggler, mpeg2-ts

I'm trying to multicast a video using `xuggler`. So far I'm able to read the video frames in `BufferImage` object. But I don't understand how to create a `mpeg-2 ts` stream and send to network. My client program doesn't support `rtsp` or `rtmp` so I need to send `raw udp` or `rtp`. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214422/how-to-transmit-live-video-from-within-a-java-application), `IContainer` directly writing to `rtmp server`. But how can generate a `udp packet(mpeg-2 ts encoded)` for sending to network?

Comment: Seven mpeg ts packets fit into a udp packet. So create a mpeg-ts, spit it into chunks of 7 frames, and send it to a multicast address and you have your raw udp stream.... Use vlc for testing, enter the url like this: `udp://@139.1.2.3:1234`.