# Creating an RTMP Stream from a changing BufferedImage

Tags: java, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp, xuggler

I currently have a program which can grab a BufferedImage from a webcam input whenever it needs. I'm now looking for a method/library to encode this into an RTMP stream. Xuggler seemed like a good option in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214422/how-to-transmit-live-video-from-within-a-java-application), but from what I can tell, it seems very outdated and poorly maintained. Xuggler appears to be built on top of FFMPEG - would I be able to achieve this with FFMPEG alone instead? I'm fairly unfamiliar with FFMPEG but can look into it if it's worth looking into.

Essentially, I want to achieve a program which can livestream a webcam - but this MUST be from a constantly changing BufferedImage, as I want to manipulate the webcam output with this BufferedImage later on.

Comment: did you get this working? i have the same use case as well

Comment: @mifol68042 Sort of, but my implementation is quite specific to the system that I'm running this application on... I made an adaptation of this, but bear in mind that you will need an OS that can support FIFO files or find a way to emulate their behavior in Windows: http://hotcoding.crombz.com/2016/02/encode-jpanel-java-swing-into-movie.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are interersted by Xuggler I am actively maintain a fork of it.
You can find it on https://github.com/olivierayache/xuggle-xuggler

Comment: Thanks for this. The link for the documentation on the repo seems to be dead however?